# Setting a Simulink model Inport value from an m file

Tags: matlab, model, simulink

I've been doing a lot of research over the last few hours and I can't seem to figure out how to get and set a value to an Inport box. I have a simple model that has one inport and one outport and they are connected to each other. I want to set the inport value to 2 and run my simulation and see if my outport got set correctly. I read that you can't use set_param to set that value but you have to use sim(), but I'm not having any luck with that. So if anyone know how to look at the data in the inport box and/or how to set it, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ports `in` and `out` in Simulink don't work as you think. They are needed when you create subsystem - your own Simulink block, than you'll have your `in` and `out` ports.

But when you just want a make some model, and pass some data in it, and get results to Matlab, then you need `To workspace` and `From workspace` blocks. Some variable-name is assigned in their options, so you can set input data from your `.m` file and get results in matlab variables.

Block `From workspace` takes matrix variable, but if you want to pass just a number, you can use block `Const` and fill it value with a variable name.

Here is a screenshot, an example of `in`, `out`, `to workspace` and `const` blocks:
[image]
Here in example, I have input parameter *x* (block `const`), subsystem `Gain5` and output parameter y (block `To workspace`). Inside the subsystem I use `in` and `out` blocks to get and return values.

Comment: Hello! I'm new to this matlab/Simulink stuff but at work I'm working on a new project, and we had this working before. We connected to matlab through eclipse/java useing JMatLink.dll, jimc.jar and jimserver.jar. During that we had a file that pulled out all the inports and outports from a model and we'd set them in eclipse run the model and get the data and output it. But if we used anything outher than doubles we'd get a crash when we ran the simulink test.

Comment: So we were going to try and write it ourselves so we might be able to change the data to something else before Simulink gets it. I read that anything that gets passed in to Simulink is a double, and that won't work for us. It's been done before using the inport block I just need to figure out how the "Jim" person did it. Thanks ^^

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't worked with Matlab from java. In fact, by default, Matlab accept everything as matrices. For example if you pass `x=5` to block `To Workspace`, it will save matrix 1xn with all values =5. But all blocks are configurable. So maybe, when you describe your model, you should configure your `in` and `out` ports correctly

Comment: engEvalString() can be used to set the vaule to Inports and Outports. I just don't know how it does it. I picked apart JMatLink.dll and I found that out. engGetVariable can be used to get the value of the outport. I just need to figure out how these functions do that so I can write my own functions to do what I need. Thanks for the responses ^^

Comment: Is there any way I can get the end data from a Simulink model from an m file? I can set the data from the M file using the constant blocks value parameter, but the ‘to workspace’ block requires me to have a variable declared. I want to have a block that I can just get_param() on and not have it have it set to a variable. The above method will only work for doubles so I want to try to do everything from an M file rather than through their dll. Thanks.

Comment: @LucasKeaton, I'm not sure, but maybe you need to try solve your problem with simulink s-functions? They have rich matlab API, you can get the result of function (like a simulink block). http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/sfg/f7-67622.html